# MySQL get records for monthly invoice taking different length of months into account

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql-date-functions

I have a database table called `subscriptions`. Each row in the table has a `created_at` date, from this day on, every month (afterwards) the subscription must be invoiced.

So on `2017-05-29`, all subscriptions with a `created_at` day == '29' must be invoiced, regardless the month or year. So I thought of this:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE DAY(created_at) = DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

But in that case I get in trouble when the previous month has 30 days, because on the 30th, it returns 30, but on the 31st it also returns 30. So all subscriptions with a `created_at` day '30' will be invoiced twice. Also February will give issues.

Another issue is the other way around, how will I invoice 2017-03-31 if there is no 31st day in April.

I could do multiple check in PHP and check if already invoiced that month etc. But I wonder if I could just fix this with MySQL.

I created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd5f71/2) example, based on the query above with some dates that will fail.

```
# Create subscription table
CREATE TABLE `subscription` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

# Fill subscription table
INSERT INTO `subscription` (`id`, `company`, `created_at`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Acme', '2017-04-15 09:56:00'),
    (2, 'Equmbo', '2017-02-28 10:00:00'),
    (3, 'Megajo', '2017-03-31 08:10:34'),
    (4, 'Astrotude', '2017-04-30 08:10:49');

# This is my base query for monthly invoice
SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE DAY(created_at) = DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));

# On 28th March, also fine
SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE DAY(created_at) = DAY(DATE_SUB('2017-03-28', INTERVAL 1 MONTH));

# But on 29th March, Equmbo is invoice again
SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE DAY(created_at) = DAY(DATE_SUB('2017-03-29', INTERVAL 1 MONTH));

# On 30st April, Astrotude AND Megajo must be invoiced. Only Astrotude returns.
SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE DAY(created_at) = DAY(DATE_SUB('2017-04-30', INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

Comment: How about something like: if LAST_DAY() = CURDATE() target all dates with a day value > than today's number?   ... I'll see if I can turn that into an answer (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: @mickmackusa, I see where you are going, but I don't know how to get it done yet!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Strawberry has a valid point in that link.  Please role model good question asking behavior by editing your question to include a small sample set.  This will increase the educational quality of your question.  If you do so, I will upvote your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE
    /* don't invoice new subs from this month */
    LAST_DAY(created_at)<LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
    AND
    (
    /* exactly match sub's day value with today's day value */
    DAY(created_at)=DAY(CURDATE())
    OR
    /* on last day of month, match sub's day if greater than today's day */
    (CURDATE()=LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) AND DAY(created_at)>DAY(CURDATE()))   
    )
```

[CURDATE()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-curdate-function.php) and [LAST_DAY()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-last_day-function.php) return a full date string (yyyy-mm-dd).

[DAY()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-day-function.php) returns an integer (d or dd).

Comment: This is really awesome! The last part is the most difficult, I couldn't figure that out myself!

Comment: @Timo002  I needed to make a small correction/refinement.  It is unnecessary for the final condition to check for `>=`.  The `DAY()=DAY()` before the `OR` already checks for `=`.  There is no point in checking for `=` again after the `OR`.  I have updated my answer and I recommend making this micro-adjustment in your project.